# How can I share SwiftData @Model between widget and app?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, widgetkit, swift-data

I have an App Group shared between my app and its widgets.

I have SwiftData's @Model, updated from the widget intent's `perform()` method and displayed on the app and the widget.

```swift
@MainActor
func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
    let context = try ModelContainer(for: MyModel.self).mainContext
    let myModel = try ModelContainer(for: MyModel.self).mainContext.fetch(
        FetchDescriptor<MyModel>(predicate: #Predicate {
            // The predicate is not the problem.
        })
    ).first

    myModel?.functionThatModifiesMyModel()

    return .result()
}
```

Both the app and the widget SwiftUI views access to the model using Macros.

```swift
@Environment(\.modelContext) var context
@Query(sort: \.whatever) var myModel: [MyModel]
```

But the data is never correct in the app code (the widget's data is updated correctly using the intent).

Why doesn't the model make it to the app?

Answer (score 1):

The first issue I see here is that you're creating 2 different instances of `ModelContainer`, each providing you with "`mainContext`". This is probably your main issue.

Create a static property holding the container's context in a file that both targets have access to:

```swift
static private var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
    let schema = Schema([
        MyModel.self,
    ])
    let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

    do {
        return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
    } catch {
        fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
    }
}()

static var sharedModelContext = ModelContext(Self.sharedModelContainer)
```

This way you ensure you always manipulate the same container and same context.

Answer (score -3):

Should enable `iCloud` (`CloudKit` & its `Containers`) for both main target and widget target instead of App Group